# Navigation Properties using 2 different Database Views

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an Account object that contains an "Id" field, which is mapped to a View in the database:

```
public class Account : GeneralInfo
    {
        [Column("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Column("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Designation { get; set; }

        [Column("full_name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column("member_type")]
        public string MemberType { get; set; }

        [Column("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Column("paid_thru")]
        public DateTime? PaidThru { get; set; }

        [Column("member_record")]
        public bool MemberRecord { get; set; }

        [Column("category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public virtual Subscription Subscriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a Subscription object that uses the same "Id" as the account object:

```
[Table("Subscriptions")]
public class Subscription
{
    [Column("Id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Column("Balance")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to use "subscription" as a navigation property of account, I get an error saying:  `{"Invalid column name 'Subscriptions_ID'."}`

How can I access "subscriptions" using the Account object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fluent API to map the Shared PK relationaship.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...........

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().HasRequired()
           .WithOptional(a => a.Subscriptions);
    }
}
```